# how to fix this coupon_store error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/52/11847652/html/coupons/wp-content/themes/deals/taxonomy-coupon_store.php on line 9

This is the [url page](http://coupons.amazkart.in/stores/flipkart/) which giving this error.

```
<?php
$taxonomy='coupon_store';
$term = get_queried_object();
//get my store.
$store_obj = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'coupon_store' );
foreach ( $store_obj as $element ) {
    $store_id = $element->term_id;
    $store_name = $element->name;
    $store_description = $element->description;
    $store_count = $element->count;
    $store_url = get_term_link( $element, 'coupon_store' );
}
$store_url = get_metadata('coupon_store', $store_id, 'junkie_store_url', true);
$store_aff_url = get_metadata('coupon_store', $store_id, 'junkie_store_aff_url', true);
$store_image_preview = junkie_get_store_image_url($store_id, 'term_id', 100);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 
    $taxonomy='coupon_store'; 
    $term = get_queried_object(); //get my store. 
    $store_obj = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'coupon_store' );
    if(!empty($store_obj)) 
    {
     foreach ( $store_obj as $element ) 
     { 
      $store_id = $element->term_id; 
      $store_name =  $element->name; 
      $store_description = $element->description; 
      $store_count = $element->count; 
      $store_url = get_term_link( $element, 'coupon_store' ); 
     } 
    }
    $store_url = get_metadata('coupon_store', $store_id, 'junkie_store_url', true);
    $store_aff_url = get_metadata('coupon_store', $store_id, 'junkie_store_aff_url', true);
    $store_image_preview = junkie_get_store_image_url($store_id, 'term_id', 100);
```

?>

Comment: not worked it gives this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/content/52/11847652/html/coupons/wp-content/themes/deals/taxonomy-coupon_store.php on line 6

Comment: please try this again

Comment: worked but not displaying store image,store link and and description like this one hope you will help me fix this also 
http://demo.theme-junkie.com/?theme=deals

Comment: please explain one thing what is this $post->ID; might be $post->ID blank and you can print the data like 
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($store_obj ); echo "<pre>";
$store_obj might be also blank... please check ...

Comment: no need to check thanks bro your code works for me after adding the coupon :) thanks a lot

Comment: hey bro do you know how to cloak links to hide it from search engines

Comment: you have used yoast plugin for search engines ??

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gKGNDCunW8 please see this video .. hope this help

Comment: hey can you help with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168756/how-to-get-this-function-in-wordpress-theme-which-will-directly-open-the-link-in

Answer (score 0):

This error is produce because of `empty variable`.

You need to check if variable is empty or not.

See below sample code for that,

```
$coupons = array();
if( !empty($coupons) )
{
    foreach ($coupons as $coupon)
    {
        //Do your Stuff.
    }
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: i am zero at this pls tell me where to put this code

Comment: Before your `foreach` loop, add `if` condition to check variable is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the

```
$post->ID
```

i think post->ID blank. please check.