# how to get this function in wordpress theme which will directly open the link in new tab

Tags: wordpress

both have same wordpress theme but there is a difference coupon should be copied and should be opened in new tab no pop up window should be opened to ask open site my link is

`enter code here`http://couponsgrabber.in/coupon/rs-300-purchase-rs-2499/

and want like this

http://www.bigrockcouponcodes.in

Answer (score 0):

if you can change some code then it is very easy.

First : you can need change css class

```
a.coupon-code-link {
    background: url("images/bg-coupon-code-left.gif") no-repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

change in to

```
a.coupon-code-link1 {
    background: url("images/bg-coupon-code-left.gif") no-repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Second :

```
You can need find correct file where add this class [coupon-code-link]

coupon-code-link class change in to  coupon-code-link1


<a data-clipboard-text="NTCV7WCSVH" target="_blank" class="coupon-code-link" id="coupon-link-94" href="http://coupons.amazkart.in/view-coupon/rs-300-purchase-rs-2499/94"><span>Show Coupon Code</span></a>
                    </div>
```

change into

```
<div class="link-holder">
                                                <a data-clipboard-text="NTCV7WCSVH" target="_blank" class="coupon-code-link1" id="coupon-link-94" href="http://coupons.amazkart.in/view-coupon/rs-300-purchase-rs-2499/94"><span>Show Coupon Code</span></a>
                    </div>
```

and it will work fine.

hope this help !

can you try

Comment: Its Worked But You See This One No Coupon Code Shown : http://coupons.amazkart.in/coupon/womens-day-deal-upto-50-best-selling-products/

Comment: Bro... Please change this class {a.coupon-code-link span} change to {a.coupon-code-link1 span}

Comment: i have check your class .. changes are not reflected.. please check

Comment: instead of it can we give copy command when clicked and link will be opened in new page

Comment: i have changed it this is the code a.coupon-code-link span1 {
 background:url("images/bg-coupon-code-right.gif") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
 color:#78691B;
 display:block;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:bold;
 line-height:16px;
 padding:4px 40px 4px 9px;
 text-transform:uppercase;

Comment: No Bro .. it's wrong... please check below class .. please set the css ..
a.coupon-code-link span change into a.coupon-code-link1 span
line no 1180.

Comment: changed but neither code shows nor copied this is the link http://coupons.amazkart.in/coupon/womens-day-deal-upto-50-best-selling-products/

Comment: i have already open this link.
and css are not changed according to class. why?
css are not reflected ..

Comment: i have changed this this is the code in css a.coupon-code-link1 {
    background: url("images/bg-coupon-code-left.gif") no-repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.couponAndTip {
 width:500px;
}
.single-coupon .couponAndTip {
}
.link-holder {
 float:left;
 margin:3px 0 -8px;
 padding-left:7px;
}
a.coupon-code-link1 span

Comment: i have added screenshot .. please check

Comment: Done bro i have check ... :-)

Comment: only pic have changed but when clicked niether code shows on current window nor coupon code copied pls check this link i want actually like this http://www.couponmama.in/coupons/upto-50-off-extra-20-off-on-rs-1999-myntra/

Comment: you want also tooltip... like "click to copy & open site" ??

Comment: ok ok got it. coupon code does not show after click .. right?

Comment: Yes,I also want tooltip... like "click to copy & open site"

Comment: Please change this file .. hope this help
script type='text/javascript' src='http://coupons.amazkart.in/wp-content/themes/clipper/includes/js/theme-scripts.js?ver=1.5.1'></script>

Comment: change all class coupon-code-link changes into coupon-code-link1

Comment: please tell me what to change in this file

Comment: please first take backup file.. and search  "click to copy & open site" in themes.. where is exists? can you search?

Comment: i have check this http://coupons.amazkart.in/coupon/womens-day-deal-upto-50-best-selling-products/ 
Tooltip is working ... but again show in popup .. same condition apply again... please code comment in js file which below in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached screenshot according changes please check

[image: please check before changes]

[image: please check after changes]

Answer (score 0):

please change this code in js file

```
jQuery(".coupon-code-link1").zclip({
    copy: jQuery(this).data('clipboard-text'),
    afterCopy:function(){
//
}


});

jQuery( document ).on('click', '.coupon_type-coupon-code a.coupon-code-link1', function() {
            var couponcode = jQuery(this).data('clipboard-text');
            var linkID = jQuery(this).attr('id');

            jQuery(this).fadeOut('fast').html('<span>' + couponcode + '</span>').fadeIn('fast');



            jQuery(this).parent().next().hide();



            /*jQuery.colorbox({
                href: clipper_params.ajax_url + "?action=coupon-code-popup&id=" + linkID,
                transition:'fade',
                maxWidth:'100%',
                onLoad: function() {
                    if ( clipper_params.is_mobile ) {
                        jQuery('#cboxOverlay, #wrapper').hide();
                    }
                },
                onComplete: function() {
                    ZeroClipboard.config( { moviePath: clipper_params.templateurl + '/includes/js/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf' } );
                    var clip = new ZeroClipboard( jQuery('#copy-button') );
                    clip.on( 'complete', function( client, args ) {
                        jQuery("#copy-button").html(clipper_params.text_copied);
                    });
                    clip.on( 'mouseover', function( client ) {
                        jQuery("#copy-button").addClass('hover');
                    });
                    clip.on( 'mouseout', function( client ) {
                        jQuery("#copy-button").removeClass('hover');
                    });
                    clip.on( 'noflash', function( client ) {
                        jQuery("#copy-button").remove();
                    });
                    clip.on( 'wrongflash', function( client ) {
                        jQuery("#copy-button").remove();
                    });
                },
                onCleanup: function() {
                    ZeroClipboard.destroy();
                    if ( clipper_params.is_mobile ) {
                        jQuery('#wrapper').show();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;*/
        });

    }
```

please try..

Comment: changed on click only code shows up but site not opened in new tab

Comment: sorry but i cant understand what to change

Comment: In last "return false" also in comment and then check

Comment: Ok bro wait.. i will try

Comment: please try again .. again check  answer and edit in your file

Comment: tried the code but now the code is not showing up in current window and nor copied after click

Comment: Bro try try Again

1 : http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/archive/jquery.zclip.1.1.1.zip

Download the zip file and please one file need include in themes.

File name : jquery.zclip.js

and then again copy and paste the answer.

Comment: not worked you can check code also not shows on current window after click

Comment: please tell me . this theme is free or paid?

Comment: please include the  jquery.zclip.js file.. i have check this file does not exists...

Comment: if theme is free available then send the link

Comment: paid but can access on multiple sites

Comment: where to paste it i have paste it in same folder

Comment: i have one more theme like this i can send you that

Comment: bro ... if u have any link regarding send me link on email
neeraj.abstain@gmail.com

Comment: pls help how to fix this i will send you the theme i am using

Comment: theme is send to you pls fix it and let me know what to change